# WP_Query in the init hook

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

the next chunk of code give me an error. The init hook is fire to early to have acces to: array($post->ID). If I use the 'wp' hook, the 'var_dump($all_dash_for);' always return 'null'.

I'm using this code for a plugin metabox in the admin area. When I'm editing a custom post type, I want to exclude the post id of the query. Any ideas? thx

```
function dash_for() {

global $all_dash_for, $post;
$all_dash_for = array();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sliding_panel',     
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
);

// Query the posts:
$panel_for_query = new WP_Query($args);


while ($panel_for_query->have_posts()) : $panel_for_query->the_post();

    $dash_for = get_post_custom_values('_dash_for');

    if(!empty($dash_for)){
        array_push($all_dash_for, $dash_for[0]); 
    } 

endwhile;    
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();    

if ( empty( $all_dash_for ) ) {
    array_push($all_dash_for, 'empty');     
}


var_dump($all_dash_for);

}

add_action( 'init', 'dash_for' );
```

Comment: i didnt get what actually problem is but you can hook your function to `wp_head`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, with admin_head it work!! wp_head is not for the admin area.

Comment: yup i wasnt aware of where your code is being used .